Add images to sidebar of a quarto website
I'm building a quarto website and my for my homepage .qmd file looks like the following:
---
title: ""
about: 
  template: solana
  image: Headshot.jpg
---

# Hellow

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 

::: {#second-column}
![](images/image1.JPG)
:::

::: {#first-column}
![](images/image2.JPG)
:::


This works but the problem is I want to put images in the left and right sidebars where no text/objects can go. The below image shows where I want the images to go:

However my images remain centered in the page. I have not modified the css at all since I ma less familiar with its conventions, but I assume this may be necessary to do for a solution.
How can I move images to the side of the quarto website?

The left side is usually reserved for the sidebar, but I like to claim more of the space by modifying grid in the yaml below and specifying sidebar: style: docked (instead of default floating).
The right margin is easy enough. You can specify a number of built in classes, such as .column-margin. See https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/article-layout.html#margin-content
Here's an example:
_quarto.yml
project:
  type: website
  output-dir: _site

website:
  title: "Test Website"
  search: false
  reader-mode: false
  sidebar:
    title: "Test Website"
    style: docked
    collapse-level: 2
    contents:
      - section: "Sidebar Section"
        contents:
          - "index.qmd"

format:
  html:
    embed-resources: true
    theme:
      light: lumen
    toc: true
    toc-expand: true
    toc-depth: 4
    toc-location: right
    toc-collapsed: false
    grid:
      sidebar-width: 300px
      body-width: 1000px
      margin-width: 500px
      gutter-width: 1.5rem

index.qmd
---
title: Home page
---

Text here

::: {.column-margin}
![](assets/my-image.png)
:::

After a quarto render, here's the result:


Thanks, this is very helpful! Is there a way to keep the image in the "about:
template: solana
image: Headshot.jpg" of the index.qmd in the same spot, rather than forcing it to the outside of the  other images that follow in the document?

Ah, I overlooked that. It looks like those templates are geared specifically toward About pages and have all sorts of custom layouts with the html/css. https://quarto.org/docs/websites/website-about.html#templates . I couldn't get that image specified in the yaml to play nice with margin images. I'd personally just omit the template and only use margin images with .column-margin if I wanted to do more images, unless you want to play with the HTML/CSS and maybe get something workable.
